# I want my player (image) to move left and right

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to programing and I need help to move my player (image) to left and right (hopefully with keybindings)

I really don't know what I'm doing and I just need help, please help

Here's my code so far:

```
import pygame

# Intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# Resulution?
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Title and Logo
pygame.display.set_caption("Båtisens Herre")
icon = pygame.image.load('img.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Background
background = pygame.image.load("bakgrunn.png")

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('King Arthur2.png')
playerX = 100
playerY = 200

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

#game loop 

running = True
while running:

    # RGB (red, green blue)
    screen.fill((248, 58, 226))
    playerY -=0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

#Background(2)
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0,))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the x-coordinate of the player. For instance move the player by pressing <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd>:

```py
#game loop 

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        playerX -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerX += 1

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0,))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Explanations:

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

---

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

---

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(100)
> ```

runs 100 times per second.